# Line breaks on varchar2 not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC C# with Entity Framework as my ORM and Oracle as my Database.

I have a table that has a column of type `varchar2` named `Body`. The table has one record only, and inside this record the Body column has:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec nunc vitae diam suscipit convallis. Nunc id sapien justo. Nulla pellentesque, lacus non congue feugiat, sem nisi bibendum nulla, nec pellentesque sem sem eget lorem.
>
> Pellentesque blandit, felis sit amet malesuada fringilla, metus risus bibendum magna, ut scelerisque nisi tellus nec lacus.

But when I display the content of that record on my webpage, I get:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus nec nunc vitae diam suscipit convallis. Nunc id sapien justo. Nulla pellentesque, lacus non congue feugiat, sem nisi bibendum nulla, nec pellentesque sem sem eget lorem. Pellentesque blandit, felis sit amet malesuada fringilla, metus risus bibendum magna, ut scelerisque nisi tellus nec lacus.

The new line character is not interpreted! What is causing this? How can I resolve this issue?

The code for my controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult PreviewEmail(int id)
{
    var campaign = _campaignService.OpenById(id);
    var emailTemplate = _commsService.GetEmailWithSeverity(campaign.Severity.ToString());
    var model = new EmailVM()
    {
        CampaignRef = campaign.Reference,
        Body = emailTemplate.Body
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers usually display all whitespace as a single space.

If you replace all newlines with `<br />`, the newlines will show up as (line/section) breaks.

You propbably want to do the replacement in the presentation layer of your code.

```
    Body = emailTemplate.Body.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: In addition to what @Klas suggested, at oracle end, the same can be achieved as `SELECT replace(Body, chr(10), '<br />') from ....`

Comment: Thank you guys, that worked great, but I also had to use `@Html.Raw(Model.Body)` in my view to get Razor to render the HTML.